# Check if coroutine exists before attempting to call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to check to see if a coroutine exists (by it's string name) before running it. Calling `StartCoroutine("NonexistantFunction")` returns `Coroutine couldn't be started` error. Wrapping the `StartCoroutine` call within `try {} catch {}` doesn't handle the error and so it is still occurs. Is there a way to handle this error or check if a function exists (by string name) before calling `StartCoroutine`?

Edit: More context, code.
So essentially I have an array of a class

```cs
public static class Commands
{
    public static Command_Test[] commands = new Command_Test[]
    {
        new Command_Test(
            "help",
            "HELP",
            "Run help for help",
            new string[] {"/help", "?", "/?"}
        )
    }
}
```

This array holds commands that the player can run. I'm using `StartCoroutine` to call these functions as I'm also passing parameters into the called function (such as arguments for the command).

```cs
     public void RecieveInput(string command, string[] args)
     {
         Command_Test cmd = getCommand(command);

         if (cmd != null)
         {
             Debug.Log($"Ran command {command} with args {strArrayToStr(args)}");

             cmdFunctions.StartCoroutine(cmd.runFunctionName, args);
         }
    }
```

So referencing the coroutine directly (`StartCoroutine(CoroutineName)`) isn't preferred as currently data is easier to edit/modify.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share the code.

Comment: You could use reflection for this, but why? What is your use case where you don't know if a function will exist or not?

Comment: How do you retrieve elements from this array? Why would you have commands in there that don't have corresponding coroutine methods?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Because the coroutines exist in another script I can't confirm that they exist (I may forget to write one, etc....) and as I'm calling the function by string name (due to how my data is stored) the function may not exist, even though called.

Comment: @UnholySheep It's more of a thing if I haven't implemented a function yet and to not cause an error, or handle the error myself.

Comment: @ShafqatJamilKhan Code has been added :)

Comment: Don't use coroutines as they teach bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.  Invoking one via magic strings doubly-so.  Consider using `async/await`, something Unity has had for some time now

Comment: @MickyD Thanks for the tip. I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the parameter as a string name, maybe it would be better just to call the function inside the `StartCoroutine()`.

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndPrint(4f));
}

private IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
}
```

If you need to call it by name, can you upload your code as well?

Comment: Thanks! Just missed it :p

Comment: This is an option but then I have to create a reference to a static class that holds the data (which I'm getting the function names from). Please check the edit made.